# Bash скрипт получающий команды из MySQL и выполняющий их.

Tags: unix, debian, bash, perl

**Суть:**

Система: **Debian**

Из **cron**, каждые 2 мин, запускается **bash** скрипт ( *Возможно это может быть не bash скрипт, я только начал постигать азы unix* ), в котором:

1) Получаем команды из удаленной базы данных **MySQL**

2) Исполняем полученные команды

Как это реализовать? Как это реализовать правильно?

P.S. Возможно нужно это делать на Perl, или как то по другому? Подскажите пожалуйста...

[Вот похожий Perl скрипт](http://adminnotes.net/directadmin-mysql-backup-каждого-пользователя-в-свою-папк/), но не уверен, стоит ли он по умолчанию в Debian6?

Comment: perl стоит по умолчанию в debian, по крайней мере начиная с potato. 
исполнять полученные команды можно просто `|sh` :

get_commands.sh |sh

Comment: Какого рода команды вы получаете из MySql? 

Можете чуть детальней описать проблему, возможно вы не с той стороны подошли.

Comment: Смысл следующий: Из PHP в MySQL добавляю команду типа "wget http://URL", а на другой машинке под Debian, я вытаскиваю из той базы данных команды, которые надо исполнить.

Нужно это для того, что бы, допустим скачивать файл какой либо, не боясь ограничения выполнение PHP скрипта в 30 сек и тд...

Comment: пример я дал, команда получает строки запросом, строки отправляем на pipe sh, всё.

Comment: @Flasko Там комменты кончились, поэтому здесь. inetd, xinetd и др. (в ubuntu виртуальный пакет inet-superserver) -- супердемоны. Они могут слушать много портов, tcp и udp и при установке соединения вызывают назначенный этому порту обработчик-сервис, подставляя сокет соединения в stdin/stdout. (у меня не установлен). Были популярны в прежние времена, позволяя создавать простые сервисы, которые могли про порты ничего не знать. Недостаток -- лишнее время на запуск сервиса, достоинство -- сервис не торчит в памяти (реальной/виртуальной).

Comment: @alexlz, я бы сказал, что принципиальный недостаток это даже не само время на запуск, а "независимость" от всех остальных (в том числе предыдущих) соединений по тому же порту.

Во многом отсюда и большое время запуска (сам-то vfork+exec это копейки). Все связанное с конфигом сервиса и его логгингом при каждом запуске (новом соединении) надо проходить по новой.

Comment: @avp это да. Но для простых сервисов это несущественно

Comment: Вы сказали "Были популярны в прежние времена", сейчас имеется какой-то более удобный/практичный аналог?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Flasko](/users/11861/flasko)](/users/11861/flasko), вот ребята подкинули пример для хinetd откуда-то из сети. Сами можете посмотреть там же.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "connection received"
```

/etc/xinetd.d/testservice has this content:

```
service testservice
{
        disable         = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        port              = 5900
        log_on_success += USERID
        log_on_failure += USERID
        server          = /usr/local/bin/testservice
        user            = root
        instances       = UNLIMITED
        wait            = no
        log_type        = SYSLOG daemon debug
}
```

In /etc/services I added this line:

```
testservice        5900/tcp
```

Then I restarted `xinetd` with `service xinetd restart`

И все это как обычно описано в `man xinetd` и **SEE ALSO** в нем.

(у меня просто комментарии закончились, а разговор переключился на "демоническую" тему,
вот и написал ответ не на сам вопрос).

Comment: Спасибо)

Все, что я описал в своем комментарии можно реализовать через xinetd?

И как его установить на debian?

Comment: @Flasko, xinetd для каждого соединения будет запускать указанную (Вашу) программу, связывая ее stdin/stdout с сокетом клиента.

Думаю, что реализовать можно. Если не гнаться за супернадежностью, то можно и sh скриптом.

На ubuntu ставится 

    sudo apt-get install xinetd

на debian видимо так же.

Comment: Установил, спасибо.

Несколько вопросов:
1) При использовании такого подхода с сокетами и xinetd будет ли висеть PHP скрипт во время выполнения команд на удаленной машинке? (Как я уже говорил, основная цель для меня, это автономное выполнение команд)
2) Как в bash скрипте выполнить строку?
3) В каком виде в bash скрипт передаеются данные?
4) Как принять эти данные в bash скрипте?
5) Можно ли вместо bash запускать perl скрипты

Comment: @Flasko
1) А как Вы хотите? Что за команды? И если они что-то выводят, что делать с выводом?
2) Вопрос неясен. Варианты разные: eval, обратные апострофы...
3) Тоже непонятно. Обычный текст.
4) ??? команда read.
5) и perl скрипты тоже.

Comment: 1) Я уже писал, что мне надо, что бы PHP скрипт отдал команды и завершил работу. А команды должны выполнится автономно. 

Просто если допустим с помощью команды wget какчается файл размером 1гб, то PHP скрипт не должен все это время висеть запущенным.

Comment: @Flasko, а что тут непонятно?

ПХП скрипт открывает сокет через fsockopen (соединяется с xinetd). Пишет данные (или команды или просто параметры, которые sh-скрипт будет использовать для закачки). Закрывает сокет и делает что ему положено дальше.

В момент соединения xinetd запускает Вашу программу (sh-скрипт). Она читает из stdin (реально это сокет в ПХП) команды (или параметры) **и запоминает!!!** их. 

После завершения потока от ПХП (stdin закроется) она выполняет заданные команды, пишет в лог, что происходит и т.п.

Все.

Comment: @avp, @altxlz, спасибо вам большое за ответы)

Возникли ошибки непосредственно с использование xinetd, подробно описал все в теме: http://hashcode.ru/questions/209368/socket-работа-с-xinetd-запуск-переданных-из-php-сокета-команд

Answer (score 3):

man mysql

```
 mysql -u user -p passwd -e 'select * from mytab' myDB | sed -e 1d | sh
```

О том, что пароли держать в открытом коде в скриптах не надо, знают все. Поэтому для данного user'а лучше обеспечивать вход без пароля

```
 mysql -u user -e 'select * from mytab' myDB | sed -e 1d | sh
```

(Внимание, сначала была очепятка -- пропущено `-e`)

Ну и можно чуть иначе

```
 cat mysqlcommans.txt | mysql myDB | sed -e 1d | sh
```

(Добавлено удаление имени таблицы, т.е. первой строки `sed -e 1d`)

Comment: зачем там sed ? mysql -N

Comment: man выдает:
Нет справочной страницы для mysql

Comment: @eicto значит и мне надо читать man mysql

@Flasko возможно не поставлена. Тогда читать документацию на dev.mysql.com

Comment: @alexlz, вряд ли на практике все получится настолько просто.

Видимо, выполненные команды надо удалять из базы. А если команда TEMPORARY FAIL? 

Что делать с параллельным доступом?

Ну, и т.д. 

Я это к тому, что нормальную распределенную работу с базой трудно сделать (а на скриптах, тем более).

--

Возможно автору лучше подойти к своей задаче с другой стороны и заменить СУБД специализированным демоном исполнения команд, отправляемых из PHP по сокету.

Comment: @avp Возможно. Но не исключено, что сейчас ему нужен какой-нибудь костыль для затыкания какой-нибудь дырки. Но увы, дальнейшие рассуждения уже для конкурса экстрасенсов.

Comment: Возможно автору лучше подойти к своей задаче с другой стороны и заменить СУБД специализированным демоном исполнения команд, отправляемых из PHP по сокету.

Можно поподробнее? Это наверно наиболее правильный вариант.

Comment: @Flasko, Вы задачу в целом поподробней распишите.

А так, в ПХП делаете [fsockopen](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=065), отправляете свою команду (текстовую строку) программе-демону (например, написанной на Си и слушающей заданный TCP порт).

Она получает эти строки, делает fork() и исполняет их в отдельных процессах. 

В простейшем случае можно использовать супер-демон inetd (xinetd) и sh скрипт, читающий stdin.

А вообще, конфигурация демона (**security**), игры с очередями, откладывание временно не исполнившихся команд и т.п. уже зависят от задачи в целом и Вашей фантазии.

Comment: @avp

      nc -k -l 7777 | sh

так?

Comment: @alexlz, тоже вариант. Самое простое.

nc что-то мне в голову не пришел. 

Но, nc форкаться не будет. И сколько он в listen() говорит не знаю. 

Т.е. это для последовательных запросов.

Comment: @alexlz, -k в nc понятно для чего. 

Я имею в виду, что пока первое соединение с nc "не отстреляется" он другие не будет обрабатывать.

Более того, сейчас проэкпериментировал в 3-х окошках с 3-мя nc, так вот, исполняются команды одного, команды второго уходят в пустоту, а когда первый завершаем, то второй тоже завершается (а запускаемые по очереди работают).

--

Про inetd я вроде писал.

Comment: @avp Виноват. Выпало из памяти. Sorry

Comment: @avp, Задача в целом: 
На сайте есть кнопка "Установить машинку", после нажатия этой кнопки, на удаленную машинку (IP, порт, ssh данные известны) должна произвестись скачка и установка различных программ (Apache допустим) и тд, а также скачка и разархивация каких либо архивов.
(Команды в определенном порядке запускаться должны. Тоесть сначала скачка архива, а затем его распаковка, не иначе) 
Ну вобщем подготовка машины к работе.
При этом, сайт, на котором кнопка "Установить машинку" не должен быть занят. Тоесть установка должна вестить автономно. (По сути через PHP отдаем команду и забывам)

Comment: Я так понял xinetd это готовый демон, который слушает порт, и когда на порт приходят данные он их передает bash или perl скрипту? Или не правильно я понял?

Как вобще через него запустить что-то? 

Или есть вариант лучше xinetd?